# puphpet exec_once logging to terminal

Tags: logging, configuration, vagrant, puphpet

I've created a super simple script that loads some configuration on startup for me. However this looks very "unclear" in the console.

How could I use the logging function of vagrant (like the elephants at the end) and hide my curl -O output??

set_server_config.sh

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
rm site.dev.conf -y
curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../raw/site.dev.conf

cd /var/www/site/system/includes/
curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../raw/config.root.php
curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../raw/config.db.php
```

Logging example:

```
==> default: Info: "... some text ..."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `==> default: Info: "... some text ..."` comes from Puppet, not shell scripts, unless you just `echo`.

Curl has a silent flag, `-s`:

`curl -s -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/.../raw/config.root.php`